# unable to install some python modules

Tags: python-3.x, pip, command-line-arguments, python-module

I am working on **windows 8.1** .When i try to install some python(python 3.4) modules and packages like `IMDBPY` using `pip` :

```
pip install imdbpy
```

I get the following error code:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ISHAN~1.
>   NIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uyc40bdk\imdbpy.

This same error message is occurring with many python modules and packages.
Although i have checked other similar questions on stack overflow but they could not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to read the `pip.log` file, you need more infos than just the exit code to debug.

Comment: What Python implementation are you using? I've had very good luck with [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/)--in fact, it's the only Python distribution for Windows with which I've been able to consistently install additional packages without such issues.

Comment: I have been using ``python.exe -m pip install foo`` on windows with good success so far. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Igor yeah on Windows it's good practice to use one of the bundled distros in order to avoid library conflicts; from, for example, the matplotlib docs: "we recommend using one of the scipy-stack compatible Python distributions such as WinPython, Python(x,y), Enthought Canopy, or Continuum Anaconda, which have matplotlib and many of its dependencies, plus other useful packages, preinstalled". Even if this isn't the issue in this case it will definitely save you some pain elsewhere.

Comment: @America, yes, I agree. I am using [WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Slim](https://winpython.github.io/) and it is working great including pip installs.